# Re-direct user when parameter query incorrect

Tags: php, mysql, database, url, parameters

So I have a script (written in PHP) that posts the user input of a reference number and postcode and then redirects the user to a page with the URL parameters like so:

> http://mydomain.com/data.php?reference=REF1234&postcode=LE1FEH

The data.php script will then fetch the data from the database according to the URL parameters, but what would I do if the reference number or postcode does not actually exist or match any row in the database - how would I send the user to an error page?

Because when they don't exist right now, the user is still directed to the data.php page - there is just no data on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// after your query:

```
if( mysql_num_rows($res) < 1 )
{
  header('Location: /errorpage/');
  exit;
}
```

Preferably, that page will have some details on the error, you can tack those pieces on to the header if you'd like. Or, you can just show an error on the page that loads the data right there.

Comment: Worked great thanks a lot :) I cannot accept the answer for another 5 minutes though

Comment: Just curious, but would this also prevent any SQL injections if a user attempts to stick in anything other than the ref. no or postcode? Or would I have to include something else for that?

Comment: @user1013930: No, at this point your query is long since executed. You absolutely must sanitize the request data prior to the query being ran. It sounds like you're just doing a straight up WHERE with your query, have you considered just populating the form as a <select> with the values that are in your database rather than letting users define their own? I think it'd be a bit nicer. Although, that too must be safeguarded against, because users can modify their HTML, even if it's a <select>.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: error.php");
die("We attempted to redirect you to error.php but could not.");
```

Possibly add javascript redirect to the die() statement. It is a good idea to add die() after redirect because bots sometimes don't follow header redirects, and will be able to see the rest of the page.